# How to convert touchstart event to mousedown correctly?

Tags: javascript, ios, touch

I have a working code based on `mousedown` event. I want to convert `touchstart` event to `mousedown` event on the beggining of the event's code to preserve existing code.

How to convert `touchstart` event to `mousedown` correctly?

Sample code with `touchstart` event:

```
var top = event.touches[i].pageY;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own event object, and then call the function you'd call for a `mousedown` event with that event object. For example:

```
var mousedownEventFunc = function (e){
   // use the event object however
   alert(e.pageX);
};

document.getElementById('selectorID').addEventListener('touchstart', function (e){
    mousedownEventFunc({
        pageX: e.touches[0].pageX,
        pageY: e.touches[0].pageY
    });
}, false);
```